# Ubound(Filter()) Function returns true for partial string matches

Tags: vba, excel, filter

Below function returns `true` for partial matches, how can I modify it to return True only if Whole string is matched.

E.g. if array has `AAA`, `A` , `BB` , `B`

and if I pass `AAA` it returns True for `A` as well.

```
Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
  IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound, , vbTextCompare)) > -1)
End Function
```

is there a simple modification to this or should I write separate code to implement that ?

Comment: I added an alternative `Filter` function coming *closest* to your original question 'Is there a simple modification?'  together with an optional parameter for whole string search and exclusion of empty strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **markers** to remove any partial matches from:

```
ary = Array("AAA", "A", "BB", "B")
```

Let's assume that the ***$*** character does not appear anywhere in the array.
We make a string like:

```
st = "$" & Join(ary, "$") & "$"
```

which is *$AAA$A$BB$B$*
If we want to see if *A* is in the array, check for `InStr(st,$A$) > 0`
If we want to see if *AAA* is in the array, check for `InStr(st,$AAA$) > 0`
etc.
If ***$*** is in the array, use something like `Chr(1)` as the marker.

**EDIT#1:**

*IMPLEMENTATION:*

```
Public Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim st As String, M As String

    M = "$"
    st = M & Join(arr, M) & M
    IsInArray = InStr(st, stringToBeFound) > 0
End Function
```

**EDIT#2:**

USAGE:

So if we wanted to see if the string ***AA*** is in the array:

```
Sub MAIN()
    ary = Array("AA", "BB", "CC", "", "DD")
    MsgBox IsInArray("$AA$", ary)
End Sub
```

and if we want to see if any of the array elements is empty:

```
Sub MAIN()
    ary = Array("AA", "BB", "CC", "", "DD")
    MsgBox IsInArray("$$", ary)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks I understand what you're saying but it would really help if you can apply it in the Function in my question.

Comment: @newguy  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: http://imgur.com/7m4oCH4 Please have a look at that why does it matches with `1` when stringtobeFound (`tbf`) is empty ? should I check if string is Empty or not before match ?

Comment: @newguy  See my **EDIT#2**

Comment: I have `Strawberry` and `Strawberry - 4 punnets` and many other strings in arr. When I search for `Strawberry` in arr I get only `Strawberry` but when I search for `Strawberry - 4 punnets` I get matches for `Strawberry` along with `Strawberry - 4 punnets`.  This is the only problem.

Comment: http://imgur.com/RDZK8fM have a look at this. Why do I get `True` for  `Strawberry` when I am looking for `Strawberry - 4 punnets`

Comment: Okay finally all problem is sorted out but after making following change.
`Public Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim st As String, M As String

    M = "$"
    st = M & Join(arr, M) & M
    IsInArray = InStr("$"  & stringToBeFound & "$" ,st) > 0
End Function`

Answer (score 1):

This **alternative** comes *closest* to the the original question *'Is there a simple modification?'*. Instead of using a different approach, it uses the same `Filter` function applied to the same (1dim) array:

**Syntax** Filter(sourcearray, match[,include [,compare]])

```
       Used compare argument: vbTextCompare, not case sensitive
                              (use vbBinaryCompare if CaseSensitive)
```

**Additional Features**

Furthermore it allows to choose between

- i)  whole string search.
- ii) partial match,

The code is tested and executes **without loss of performance**.

**Code**

```
Public Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant, Optional bFull = False) As Boolean
'  Purpose: search strings in 1dim arrays using the Filter function
'           i)  whole strings   (bFull = True) or
'           ii) partial matches (bFull = False, default)
'  Exclude empty strings "" (Note: if not wanted, comment the next line out!)
   If stringToBeFound = "" Then Exit Function
If bFull Then             ' i)  search whole strings
   IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(Split(Join(arr, ".|") & ".|", "|"), stringToBeFound & ".", , vbTextCompare)) > -1)
Else                      ' ii) partial match
   IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound, , vbTextCompare)) > -1)
End If
End Function
```

**Note**

It is to be remarked, that the `Filter` function would accept **empty** `""`-strings, too. That's why I **excluded** them in the IsInArray function as well; if you don't want that, simply comment the first code line out.